# Elasticsearch installation error due to custome resource definition

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm

how to resolve this CRD issue.

```
helm install --namespace=eck --timeout=10m0s --values=/home/shell/helm/values-eck-operator-1.5.0.yaml --version=1.5.0 --wait=true test /home/shell/helm/eck-operator-1.5.0.tgz
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: CustomResourceDefinition "elasticsearches.elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "test"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "eck"
```

Answer (score 0):

The helm doc says:

> With the arrival of Helm 3, we removed the old crd-install hooks for a more simple methodology. There is now a special directory called crds that you can create in your chart to hold your CRDs. These CRDs are not templated, but will be installed by default when running a helm install for the chart. If the CRD already exists, it will be skipped with a warning. If you wish to skip the CRD installation step, you can pass the --skip-crds flag.

So if you are using helm 3 and your crds are already created you can pass the flag `--skip-crds` to skip their creation.

Like this:

```
helm install --namespace=eck --timeout=10m0s --values=/home/shell/helm/values-eck-operator-1.5.0.yaml --version=1.5.0 --wait=true test /home/shell/helm/eck-operator-1.5.0.tgz --skip-crds
```